# Is there a way to pull data by sum one column and based on another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum amount by account by month and have the result shown in another Cell by account.

```
=AND($E1>=MONTH(E1:E8),SUMPRODUCT(($F$1:$F$8>=MONTH(E1:E8)=6*($D$1:$F$8=D1))>=0))*6
```

```
Account                 Amount          Month
06962-5001121            3.00           July
06962-5001122            3.00           July
06962-5001123            6.00           July
```

What actually happened was 0 in cell

|  | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Account | Date | Amount |
| **2** | 06962-5001121 | 2023-06-10 | 1 |
| **3** | 06962-5001123 | 2023-06-11 | 2 |
| **4** | 06962-5001121 | 2023-06-11 | 1 |
| **5** | 06962-5001122 | 2023-06-12 | 2 |
| **6** | 06962-5001122 | 2023-06-13 | 1 |
| **7** | 06962-5001121 | 2023-06-14 | 1 |
| **8** | 06962-5001123 | 2023-06-15 | 2 |
| **9** | 06962-5001123 | 2023-06-16 | 2 |

Comment: How `July` is related with column E? What's your expected result?

Comment: Make a pivot table of your data!

Comment: What is your expectations of this part? `$F$1:$F$8>=MONTH(E1:E8)=6`

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(r, D2:F9,
     m, 6,
     a, TAKE(r,,1),
     b, INDEX(r,,2),
     c, INDEX(r,,3),
     u, SORT(UNIQUE(a)),
HSTACK(u,
       MMULT(--(TOROW(a)=u),(MONTH(b)=m)*c)))
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your quick response However, that:, 06962-06962-50011121 18 Should be 3
06962-50011122 18 Should be 3
06962-50011123 36 Should be 6, It would appear the sum is multiplied by 6

Comment: Sorry P. My mistake left out the =6 after the month function. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: sorry P can I add another column to the equation  col G,  Payment
Payment
Payment
OD INTEREST
OD PROTECTION FEE
Transfer
LOAN INTEREST
MORTGAGE PAYMENT
I tried to enter d, INDEX(r,,4), and increased the a to include G unfortunately, I got a #REF once again thanks for the help.

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow and apologize if I am confusing. I found that in my download from the Business (Bank) I have two additional columns G and H. I can put the information into another sheet and do calculations there manually. What you provided me P with works great however I have been trying to add in the other two columns and keep getting #Value or #SPILL. I can index the columns with no problem but cannot get them to display on the output. Thanks again for any assistance you can give me. Norm

Comment: Spill error is typically occuring when the spill range (the size of the spill result) covers a cell which is not clear of data. If you click the cell of the formula it shows blue surroundings around where it tries to spill. Add columns if required, or clear the cells within that range if you can.

Comment: As for the extra columns, I don't know what your exact intention is with these extra columns, but likely you need to add a filter condition to the uniques and add these same conditions to the mmult, but how depends on what you require.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. However I was using a sample and it does not work on the real data.,

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. However I was using a sample and it does not work on the real data. Chequing , 06962-5001375 , 2023-08-01 ,  Cheque # ,  INSURANCE , THE PERSONAL ,  -269.88

I added the values for indexing to 7 however I get an error #Value so I changed the * C, Value to g and got another error. When I evaluated the Formula in the first a,TAKE(r,,1),I  N/A  for r,,1. I also increased the range to include column g. Would appreciate if you could help me out. As I am going crazy with the hours spent on this formula. thanks.

Comment: In that case open a new question with new (dummy) data including the extra columns and your expectations with that. PS you can post your data as markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: maybe you can share the formula you tried. I may be able to spot if something may be off.

Comment: This is the actual data:

Comment: I don't see a difference. Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited the bottom part to show as markdown table. You can generate a table like that by pasting your data directly from Excel into the table generator using the link I shared.